# What is a "nonparametric function"?

Tags: definition

I am looking for a formal definition of the term "nonparametric function."

I understand the term and I use nonparametric regressions http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_regression but I haven't been able to find a formal definition of the term.

Thanks.